# find two alike in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, count, substring

I want to find out if any rows shares ip.
I found out how to do this by using

> SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE ip IN ( SELECT ip FROM `people` GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(ip > 1 ) ORDER BY name

and from this database

> John   123.456.78.90
>   Bob    123.456.78.90
>   
> Eric    123.456.78.90

I got

> John   123.456.78.90
>   Eric    123.456.78.90

But after some changes in the database ports were added to the ip's (dont ask me why) 
so now the database looks like this:

> John   123.456.78.90:1337
>   Bob    123.456.78.90:4242
>   Eric    123.456.78.90:9001

I found out I could delete everything after the colon by doing this

> SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,':', 1)

I cant figure out how to delete everything after the colon and then see if anyone has the same ip 
 any way to mix these two queries together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX function in the grouping, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, ':', 1) IN ( SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, ':', 1) FROM people GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, ':', 1) HAVING COUNT(ip > 1 ) 
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: if i use this it will output all 3 :/

Comment: all three of the rows in your new database have the same IP. Shouldn't the query output all 3?